# Trouble installing Ecore Tools SDK

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, emf

I am using Eclipse Juno EE and I can not install the Ecore Tools SDK. I have tried everything, searched everywhere and I cant find a solution. I tried via the Install New Software Manager, the Market, I even downloaded the archive file(when I try to install it with the archive from the site it tells me that no software was found). While searching, I found that article: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/354109/ where this guy "Cedric Brun" gives a link for instalation ( http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emft/ecoretools/updates/1.1/201205140421 ). I tried the link, installed the SDK(at least I think so), but now when I click on New... There is no Ecore Tools folder with options, and I can't create Ecore Diagrams. Do someone have a solution to that problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I'm running the Eclipse Modeling package, it is already installed, but checking the update site "Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno" shows the "Ecore Tools SDK" under the category "Modeling".

Have you tried installing from that repo?
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno

Comment: I reinstalled it from the first link, but I still can't see it when I click "New"... If it's important, here is the tutorial which I am following(step 3.1 requieres to make a diagram) http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseEMF/article.html

Comment: Try: File > New > Other ... > Ecore Tools > Ecore Diagram

Comment: I don't have/see the "Ecore Tools" folder when I click on Other

Comment: Did you reinstall Eclipse from scratch? And install the Ecore tools from the Juno update site (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno)?

Comment: I deleted it and then installed the non EE version of eclipse and it worked, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

For installing Ecore Tool go to Help -> Install new software and use one of these links :

- for eclipse mars http://download.eclipse.org/ecoretools/updates/releases/3.0.1/mars
- for older versions
  http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emft/ecoretools/updates/1.2/201306071421

Note that after installation is possible that to make a new ecore diagram in the fallowing ways:

- File->New->Other...Ecore Tool->Ecore Diagram
- File->New->Other...Other->Ecore Diagram
- Via the context menu - right click on a .ecore file and select Initialize Ecore Diagram...

Also you can go to Help->Install New Software... select your eclipse release site and under Modeling check the Diagram Editor for Ecore (SDK) you will probably need Eclipse Modeling Framework SDK to.